# PHP Debugging Guessing Game: Mastermind and how do i solve it with two players

Tags: php, html

overview:

1 What this is about

2 What questions i have

3 What is bugging

**1. What this is about**

this is about programming a little number game. i think it is also known as mastermind. the game has the following rules.

- there are two players
- first the starting player types 5 numbers
- then the second player types 5 numbers to guess the numbers from the
  first player
- the programm has to echo how many numbers of the second player are at
  the right place and also how many numbers are correctly guessed.
- the programm has to run a fiew times, because player two has several
  tries
- i want to use one formular for both players if possible aka one
  submit button
- **i don't want to know how this programm is coded as a whole** but i have specific questions for some steps.

**2. What questions i have**

As you see i did player two as well. But i still have the problem that i cannot count how often player two typed the numbers. I have to count it because i want the game to quit if a certain number is reached.

Also i want to clear the screen for player two without clearing his formular, too. but the formular for player one should vanish after player ones submit.

**3. Bugs/Debugging**

i tried to use a loop but i couldn't figure out how i can use it without creating several formulars at once. it just should count + 1 for every player two submit of numbers.

```
       <html>
    <head>
      <title>guess a number</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h4> guess a number</h4>
     <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"method="post">

       <!-- player one is starting here -->
       <p>Spieler 1</p>
       <p>chose your five numbers/Wähle deine 5 Zahlen</p><br />

        <input type="password" name="one" size="1" maxlength="1">
        <input type="password" name="two" size="1" maxlength="1">
        <input type="password" name="three" size="1" maxlength="1">
        <input type="password" name="four" size="1" maxlength="1">
        <input type="password" name="five" size="1" maxlength="1">

            <input type="submit" name="gesendet" value="ok"></button> <br />
        </form>

    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['gesendet'])){

        $one = $_POST['one'];
        $two = $_POST['two'];
        $three = $_POST['three'];
        $four = $_POST['four'];
        $five = $_POST['five'];
// array to safe the input of player one with sessions
        $_SESSION['anumberone'][0] = $one;
        $_SESSION['anumberone'][1] = $two;
        $_SESSION['anumberone'][2] = $three;
        $_SESSION['anumberone'][3] = $four;
        $_SESSION['anumberone'][4] = $five;

          foreach ($_SESSION['anumberone'] as $ausgabe) {

            echo "$ausgabe";
          }
        }

        $i = 0;   // how can i count the second submits?
      while ( $i < 5 )  {
        $i = $i + 1;
        echo "$i";


          //start with player two here!
          echo "<br>";
          echo "Spieler 2";
          echo "<form method='post'>";
          echo "Ihre Ziffern:<br>";
          echo "<input type='text' name='sechs' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
          echo "<input type='text' name='sieben' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
          echo "<input type='text' name='acht' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
          echo "<input type='text' name='neun' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
          echo "<input type='text' name='zehn' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
          echo "<input type='submit' name='submitzwei' value='OK'>";
          echo "</form>";

          if(!empty($_POST['submitzwei'])){
              $sechs = $_POST['sechs'];
              $sieben = $_POST['sieben'];
              $acht = $_POST['acht'];
              $neun = $_POST['neun'];
              $zehn = $_POST['zehn'];

              $_SESSION['anumber2'][0] = $sechs;
              $_SESSION['anumber2'][1] = $sieben;
              $_SESSION['anumber2'][2] = $acht;
              $_SESSION['anumber2'][3] = $neun;
              $_SESSION['anumber2'][4] = $zehn;

              foreach ($_SESSION['anumber2'] as $ausgabe) {

                echo "$ausgabe";
              }

            }
          }


        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't understand your question please be specific  and explain clearly !

Comment: I rewrite it in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you need to use session which keeps the data until you end the session, follow the below altered code:

```
<?php
session_start();    

$eins = $_POST['eins'];
$zwei = $_POST['zwei'];
$drei = $_POST['drei'];
$vier = $_POST['vier'];
$fuenf = $_POST['fuenf'];
$_SESSION['inputeins'][0] = $eins;
$_SESSION['inputeins'][1] = $zwei;
$_SESSION['inputeins'][2] = $drei;
$_SESSION['inputeins'][3] = $vier;
$_SESSION['inputeins'][4] = $fuenf;

foreach ($_SESSION['inputeins'] as $ausgabe) {

  echo "$ausgabe<br>";
}   
/*          echo "<form>";
echo "<form action='ratespiel.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='ok' name='verstecken'>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['verstecken'])){
$ausgabe = "";
echo "$ausgabe";
} */
/* echo $input[0] . $input[1] . $input[2] . $input[3] . $input[4]; */

echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "Ihre Ziffern:<br>";
echo "<input type='text' name='sechs' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='sieben' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='acht' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='neun' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='zehn' size='1' maxlength='1'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submitzwei' value='OK'>";
echo "</form>";

if(!empty($_POST['submitzwei'])){
    $sechs = $_POST['sechs'];
    $sieben = $_POST['sieben'];
    $acht = $_POST['acht'];
    $neun = $_POST['neun'];
    $zehn = $_POST['zehn'];

    $_SESSION['inputzwei'][0] = $sechs;
    $_SESSION['inputzwei'][1] = $sieben;
    $_SESSION['inputzwei'][2] = $acht;
    $_SESSION['inputzwei'][3] = $neun;
    $_SESSION['inputzwei'][4] = $zehn;

    foreach ($_SESSION['inputzwei'] as $ausgabe) {

      echo "$ausgabe<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: its not what i want to achieve and the second input ist still not working. the thing is this: first one person types some numbers then a second person types "other" numbers. both should be safed in different arrays.

Comment: ah i see. i'll try that out. if i understand correctly after someone submitted a thing in php it is gone so the second submit wouldn't have the data from the first input anymore?

Comment: correct it will keep it for first submit later if another form submit is done 2nd form data will be in $_POST and 1st $_POST will vanish.

Comment: ok that brings me to another problem. now i cant count player two submits. Player two should be able to type his guesses a few times before the game ends but i don't know how the loop has to look like so this works. also i want to clean the screen for player two while keeping the formular for player two.

Comment: for counting, keep a session counter and increment each time you submit the form. for clearing the screen - unset session variables of the 2nd form after you process the form.